# unreal engine 4 holding down a key for a character to continually jump

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to get my player to jump continually while the key is pressed down but the while loop doesn't accept as "exec is not compatible with Boolean" is there any way to modify code so that when the button is held down the condition is met and the jump will loop until the key is released. thanks in advance
(working with blueprints in unreal engine)

Comment: Please can you show us your Blueprint? It's difficult to suggest a way of modifying code we can't see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer that will call the jump (the timer can loop).
When the char lands check the condition. It it's false clear the timer. So it'll not call jump again.

The input will change the condition from true (when hold) to false (when release)